# Является ли здесь "прежде всего" вводным или наречным выражением?

Tags: пунктуация

Особенности сегодняшнего решения вопроса, наверное, прежде всего (,) определяются большей глубиной интегрирования нашей экономики в мировую, с ее законами и стандартами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Два подряд вводных – это сильно. Попробуйте "прежде всего" переставить на одно слово вперёд. Видите, что не вводное? Кстати, и звучать будет лучше.

Comment: Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

А что здесь неясного? Здесь ''прежде всего" явное наречное выражение. Смысл в том, что решение вопроса в первую очередь определяется большой глубиной... А не в том, что "во-первых"..

Comment: Смысл в обоих случаях похожий (принципиальное значение выражения не меняется: мы что-то считаем главным, ставим на первое место), но в необособленном варианте мы логически (с уверенностью) подчеркиваем "прежде всего", и это следует после  неуверенного "наверное".

Comment: Серж, Вы, кажется, категорически отрицаете возможность сочетания "наверное, прежде всего,...", настаиваете на его о ш и б о ч н о с т и. А вот статистика говорит в пользу вашего мнения, как вы думаете? Вот очередной пример: "Наверное, прежде всего, стоит попытаться предельно честно ответить самому себе на ряд вопросов". Чаще встречается форма "наверное, прежде всего потому, что...", но не более того. Приведите примеры без обособления, объясните, почему  так часто встречающиеся варианты с обособлением вы считаете неграмотными.

Comment: Я считаю, что решение здесь должно быть авторским, и зависит от желания автора выделить или не выделить логически "прежде всего", отнести выражение к первому или второму плану речи. Оба решения правильны, и тема не должна вызывать  столь ожесточенных споров и требований однозначного ответа.

Comment: Вера, я не говорю, что такое сочетание невозможно. Я говорю, что в данном конкретном случае - это наречие. Ср.: ...наверное, прежде всего( во-первых, главное)определяется... 
А смысл-то в том, что определяется в первую очередь, а не во-первых.

Answer (score -1):

"Прежде всего" здесь, скорее, вводное слово.

Необособленное наречное выражение "прежде всего"плохо сочетается со словом "наверное" по семантике: в этом случае предположительный характер сообщения  ("наверное") противоречит конкретному утверждению ("прежде всего").

Похожий пример из газет:

"В чем мы безусловно недорабатываем ― в разъяснении своей позиции, своих действий. Наверное, прежде всего, из-за чрезмерной загруженности".

Comment: А я думаю, что "прежде всего" здесь наречное выражение, т. к. автор пишет "наверное" - он как бы не уверен в достоверности сообщения, но смысл сообщения тот, что особенности сегодняшнего решения вопроса прежде всего определяются глубиной интегрирования нашей экономики в мировую...

Comment: Да и с "определяется" выражение "прежде всего" не очень хорошо сочетается. "Определяется" (... чем-то = решающее или самое важное значение для этого имеет то-то) по смыслу содержит в себе синоним этого выражения. В сочетании с сомнением "наверное" это становится менее убедительным, поэтому стоит попытаться что-то из этого сократить.

Answer (score -1):

**Особенности сегодняшнего решения вопроса, наверное, прежде всего (,) определяются большей глубиной интегрирования нашей экономики в мировую, с ее законами и стандартами.**

---

Пунктуация языка русского - структурно-интонационная. 
Если оборот наречный - зпт. не нужна. Прежде всего я внесу воду, а печь потом (смысловое значение - сначала, перед всем другим...). Правило то же, как для слова *наконец (см. Розенталя http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/20.htm).

Если оборот эмоциональный - ударение не на первенстве, а для усиления значимости послед. высказывания, зпт. нужна.
В твоём примере именно это есть цель употребления оборота, которая усиливается неуверенностью слова наверное. 
Моя правка: Особенности сегодняшнего решения вопроса, наверное прежде всего, определяются большей глубиной интегрирования нашей экономики в мировую, с ее законами и стандартами.
Предл. корявое и нелогичное. Решают задачу, на вопрос отвечают. Большая глубина - это внесение пустопорожней неизвестности. с ее законами и стандартами - это надевание седла на корову перед выгоном на пастбище.

Мой совет: В моём (нашем) суждении (не по мнению) сегодня особенности решения этой задачи, прежде всего, определяются глубиной интегрирования нашей экономики в мировую посредством...

Comment: >> Моя правка: Особенности сегодняшнего решения вопроса, наверное прежде всего, определяются большей глубиной интегрирования нашей экономики в мировую, с ее законами и стандартами.

*Наверное прежде всего* - этта што?

>> Предл. корявое и нелогичное. Решают задачу, на вопрос отвечают.

Вопросы у нас и решают тоже, г-н офицер.

Comment: Полностью согласен! В одном из значений слово "вопрос" имеет значение: Положение, дело, задача и т.п., требующие обсуждения, разрешения; проблема.